# Why is three requests being made?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have this function to check if a username exists. It should only run after the user stops typing. So every time the user types the timer is reset and only once it gets to 3 seconds should a GET request be sent to the server. It works in the sense that I can see the counter counting from 1 to 3 and then it stops counting. If I type again the counter starts again. Only if I stop long enough does the counter reach 3. Why if I look in the console are there 3 requests (for 3 letters typed more than 3) to the api instead of just one. So it's sending a request even if the timer does not reach 3. so does the counter continue counting for a given time the user entered a character, even if it restarts?

Here is my code:

Vue html:

```
<input
    type="text"
    name="username"
    class="border pd5"
    v-model="username"
    required
    placeholder="Start typing and it will check if the username exists"
    @input="checkusername"
/>
```

Javascript:

```
const username = ref("")

function checkusername() {
    if (username.value.length > 3) {
        let time = 0;
        let timer = setInterval(function () {
            time = time + 1;
            console.log(time);
            if (time === 3) {
                clearTimeout(timer);
                axios
                    .get("api/v1/users/check/username/"+ username.value + "/")
                    .then((response) => {
                        console.log(response.data);
                    })
                    .catch((error) => {
                        console.log(error);
                    });
            }
        }, 1000);
    }
}
```

How can I make it so it just sends one request if the user stops typing? I have tried other solutions but because the function is called each time the user types they do not work for me and they all call the api multiple times, that is why I created this but it seems that no matter what the function call triggers an API call even if the counter never reaches 3.

Comment: There will be as many requests as there are checkusername calls because there are multiple simultaneous intervals. In order to avoid this, `timer` should be in component scope, not checkusername function. Btw you're trying to reinvent the wheel, it seems that you need debounce here

Comment: Yeah. Use debounce or simply listen to the change event but it forces user to press enter to trigger the event.

Answer (score 2):

The following snippet illustrates how you can wait for 3 seconds after the last keystroke before making a request, only if there are more than three characters. But I find 3 seconds too long a waiting time.

```js
var timer;

function restart(input) {
  if (timer) clearTimeout(timer);
  if (input.value.length > 3)
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
      alert("Making request with " + input.value);
    }, 3000);
}
```

```html
<input onkeyup="restart(this)" />
```